# Why does Rails new install rails 5.1.6?

Tags: rubygems, rbenv, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm reading the book "Agile Development with Rails," and following the guide. Using Rbenv I've installed rails 5.1.3. When I run "rails new demo" it automatically installs rails 5.1.6.

Although it doesn't seem like a big deal the book specifies that you should utilize 5.1.3 and I'm curious as to why this is happening. I've also noticed that running the command explicitly with rails `_5.1.3_` yields the same results when you run the bin/rails about you still end up with 5.1.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that by default the rails new command will only create applications with the latest patch version of rails. At the time of the writing of the book 5.1.3 was most likely the latest and greatest. Tried installing older versions of rails and repeated the setup process several times. I tried creating a project with rails 5.0.2 and it created a project with rails 5.0.7 which is the latest patch version for 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 16.04, using rbenv**

I just started this book, and ran into this exact same problem.  For reference, the book is Pragmatic Programmer's [Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1](https://pragprog.com/book/rails51/agile-web-development-with-rails-5-1)

**Solution:**

Open Gemfile with editor, and find this line:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
```

Edit this line to read (basically, remove the '~>'):

```
gem 'rails', '5.1.3'
```

Run `bundle install`, which returned a list of error regarding gem dependencies:

[Bash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuVms.png)

Run `bundle update`, as the error messages suggest.  Bundler now reverts to Rails 5.1.3, and reverts all the gems that depend on it ("Using rails 5.1.3 (was 5.1.6)"):

[Bash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv0BV.png)

**Explanation**

[Bundler](https://bundler.io/v1.3/rationale.html#bundlers-purpose-and-rationale) states that '~>' means "this version or above, but below the next minor version (in this case 5.2.0, see [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/))".  So '~>' is allowing Bundler to install 5.1.6 simply because it's the highest currently available.

When you update your Gemfile to `'5.1.3'`, you're telling Bundler to use that exact version.